# Get office key on a PC that won't boot

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I'm trying to get the office key (or at least the five last characters) from a pc that I'm fixing. The problem is that cscript returns:

`"ERROR DESCRIPTION: An unknown error ocurred. (0x1AB)"`

When I try to run `cscript OSPP.VBS /dstatus`

I'm running this command from the cmd on the recovery mode, as the pc won't boot.

What can I do to get the office key. I just want to know what key it is to install the correct one after I reset the computer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would be better to ask how to retrieve the Office product key from a machine that won't boot instead of asking for help implementing your proposed solution. See the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UBCD or Hirems which both have a utility to extract your Windows and Office COA and product keys. If you booted to recovery then you will be able to boot to a PE environment or bootable recovery CD or USB drive with the above mentioned boot tools. From there you can even access the network and download the utility of choice to extract your key.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, what is a PE environment?

Comment: Also, is it possible to get the Windows 10 Edition (Pro, Home, etc.) using one of these tools?

Comment: PE stands for Preinstallation Environment, hence the word 'environment' that I used in PE Environment was redundant. PE are usually loaded from live media onto a RAM disk partition without effect of the HDD and were mainly crated as a way to load Windows onto production machines enabling the OBE (Out of Box Experience) so many enjoy after buying a new PC at a retail establishment and booting said PC for the 1st time. They are also now used to run minimal Windows environments to use diagnostic, maintenance and repair tools.

Comment: The effectiveness or function of the tools mentioned that extract registration keys are not usually defined or constrained by Windows version.